# How to Trigger Disaster Recovery in Google Cloud - Compute Engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, disaster-recovery

I am usng Google Compute Engine to deploy one of the products of our company which is secured by license.
License works on the basis of machine details and thus, it is binded to the machine on which it is installed.

However, in case of Disaster Recovery we want to test how the license and overall product would behave and for that I would like to trigger Disaster Recovery manually. Is there any way of doing it? Or if there is any problem in my understanding of the Cloud service, do help.

Comment: What test do you want to perform as DR? One machine down? one region down?

Comment: one machine down

Comment: stop your machine! you will see what's happen